# MYSQL PIVOT to select data from two table

Tags: mysql, sql

iam having some problems here, i have two tables that is

```
1st Table: user
[user_id,name]
(1,"Shelby")
(2,"barray")
(3,"Obor")

2nd Table: payment_transaction
[payment_id,payment_date,payment_user_id (this refer to user id from table user), payment_amount]
(1,"2017-06-09 16:48:37",1,20)
```

i want to output it like this pivot example:

```
name | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | July .. Dec | <br>
Shelby | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | ... 0 |<br>
barray | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... 0 |<br>
Obor   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0  | ... 0 |<br>
```

i manage to get it right like using this sql:

```
    SELECT pt.name,
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 1 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Jan',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 2 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Feb',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 3 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Mar',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 4 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Apr',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 5 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'May',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 6 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Jun',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 7 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Jul',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 8 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Aug',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 9 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Sep',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 10 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Oct',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 11 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Nov',
SUM(case when month(s.payment_date) = 12 THEN s.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) 
'Dec'
from user pt left join payment_transactions on pt.user_id = s.payment_user_id group by pt.name
```

But, as soon i want to put Where clause for getting the data only on specific date like this

```
    WHERE YEAR(s.payment_date)='2017'
```

it only output this:

```
name | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | July .. Dec | <br>
Shelby | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | ... 0 |<br>
```

the two other name did not came out.

may i know where am i wrong to retrieve the data base on year?

thank you!

Comment: Ok i found the solutions. the condition for year should be put along side with join table, like this        left join payment_transactions on pt.user_id = s.payment_user_id AND YEAR(s.payment_date)='2017'